# How to host an IronPython engine in a separate AppDomain?

Tags: c#, ironpython, embedding

I am using the below code to execute the IronPython Script on separate "appDomain" from c#.
(I used this approach to resolve memory leakage issue)
The scripts which take a lesser time (less than 3 mins), executes fine.

But if the script which takes a longer time (more than 5mins) throws an exception saying 
-> System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Object '/011b230e_2f28_4caa_8bbc_92fabb63b311/vhpajnwe48ogwedf6zwikqow_4.rem'

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Scripting;

namespace PythonHostSamle
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain("sandbox");
        var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine(sandbox);
        var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Python25\Lib");
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\RevitPythonShell");
        engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);

        ScriptScope scope = engine.ExecuteFile("C:\Python25\Test.py")
        // Script takes morethan 5mins to execute(sleep in the script)

        ObjectHandle oh = scope.GetVariableHandle("GlobalVariableName")
        // System throws following exception              
        //System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException:
        // Object '/011b230e_2f28_4caa_8bbc_92fabb63b311/vhpajnwe48ogwedf6zwikqow_4.rem'

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a real solution, but as a quick fix I believe you can increase the remoting timeout for an AppDomain by setting LifetimeServices.LeaseTime.  I believe must be executed in the *target* AppDomain (have not tested though!).  The easiest way to do this would probably be to get the Python engine in the sandbox domain to set the property for you.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding InitializeLifetimeServices and returning null would be the normal approach.  I doubt that's possible in your case.  Including the [`<lifetime>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt4b8676%28VS.85%29.aspx) in the app.config file is another approach.

Comment: The override for InitializeLifetimeService seems to be missing from 2.0.x but is present in IronPython 2.6.